# Создание кнопки, которая создает страницы

Tags: javascript, php, backend

В общем и целом, задача у меня такая:
Нужно создать страницу где форма будет с 3-мя полями. После кнопка, на которую мы можем нажать и она создает страницу (пример: index/page1.... index/page2 итд.). На той странице(page1 к примеру) должен быть шаблон HTML с теми же данными, которые я ввел в форму. Не могу найти ответ на эту задачу... я не разбираюсь практически в бэкенде, поэтому, пожалуйста как получится, можете прислать код с объяснениями. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "*можете прислать код с объяснениями.*" --- нет

Comment: интересно почему минусуют рабочий ответ, человеку нужно создавать страницы, код это выполняет, в чем проблема?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

в корне сайта создайте файл craetePage.php и вставьте туда этот код

```
 <?php
    $constructor_page = '/craetePage.php';
    if(!empty($_POST['page_name'])){
      file_put_contents($_POST['page_name'],$_POST);
      header('Location: '.$_POST['page_name']);
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $constructor_page;?>" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="page_name" placeholder="/pages/page_name/page1.html">
      <input type="text" name="data1" placeholder='данные1'>
      <input type="text" name="data2" placeholder='данные2'>
      <input type="submit" value="button">
    </form>
```